# Compare the variable VS an array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, serialization

I have multiple rows in MySQL with 2 columns: ID, CatID

In particular, I used `serialize()` function for CatID's variables to convert the array and store the data into the database.

Now, I have one variable (eg: CatID = 98) and I want to compare it to the array in the database. What SQL Query I need? How can I write?

Example an array in database: `a:2:{i:0;s:2:"98";i:1;s:2:"99";}`

Answer (score 0):

```
   $query=mysql_query("SELECT CatID FROM UR_DB Where CatID=98"); 
   While($row==mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
         $catid=$row['CatID'];
    }
```

write your Database query. IF your array is like `a[1]="something"` , hope you can compare them !

Comment: CatID column stored a string `a:2:{i:0;s:2:"98";i:1;s:2:"99";}` - So I was try  `$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MY_DB Where CatID=98");` but not work :( "Empty Result"

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; print_r(urarray); echo "</pre>";` print your array and know the index what is possible to compare .